# Printing key-value pairs in a for loop in two colours

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to print key-value pairs in a for loop in two colors and I don't want to separate this into tons of lines.

Function I wrote looks like this:

```
def TABLES_ONLY_FOUR():
    TABLES_TYPES_FOUR = {
                         "TABLE 2": "4 Seats",
                         "Table 4": "4 Seats",
                         "Table 5": "4 Seats",
                         "Table 8": "4 Seats",
                         "Table 9": "4 Seats"
                     }
    for k, v in TABLES_TYPES_FOUR.items():
        print(k, v, sep=" :   ")
```

I need to print this in a column as it is. I also found some colors here:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style
```

However, for some reason, when i tried this for one line of the code, output stays in the chosen color for all other printing and this doesn't solve my problem anyway.

## Small Edit

I am using Linux Minut and the code for colorama looked like this:

```
print(Fore.RED + "xxx"
```

Questions:

1) How to change my for loop to i.e. print "Table 4" and "Table 8" with their values in Red and the rest of "Table x" in green?

2) Later on I will be referring to these "Tables", if they are marked on green or red. How to do it smoothly?

Comment: Why it is tagged with Linux?

Comment: I don't see the colorama code anywhere in your code, where is it?

Comment: Sorry, tagged this with Linux because I found some info that colors of output in Python may be somehow connected to other OS.

Comment: @Aaron Colorama will actually work on Windows or Linux, it's designed to detect environment.

Comment: oh yes it does. You have to call `colorama.init()` which redirects stdout/stderr to workaround that. And from windows 10 I guess you don't need that anymore

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre I stand corrected. deleted...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the color in the values, and use `Fore.RESET` to reset the original ink color:

```
from colorama import Fore, Back, Style, init
init()   # probably required only on Windows < Windows 10


def TABLES_ONLY_FOUR():
    TABLES_TYPES_FOUR = {
                         "TABLE 2": ("4 Seats",Fore.GREEN),
                         "Table 4": ("4 Seats",Fore.RED),
                         "Table 5": ("4 Seats",Fore.GREEN),
                         "Table 8": ("4 Seats",Fore.RED),
                         "Table 9": ("4 Seats",Fore.GREEN),
                     }
    for k, (v,col) in TABLES_TYPES_FOUR.items():
        print("{}{}: {}{}".format(col,k,v,Fore.RESET))

TABLES_ONLY_FOUR()
```

Alternative, without changing your data model as Steven suggested:

```
    for k, v in TABLES_TYPES_FOUR.items():
        print("{}{}: {}{}".format(Fore.RED if k in {'Table 4', 'Table 8'} else Fore.GREEN,k,v,Fore.RESET))
```

Comment: If OP doesn't want to hard code the color into the data structure he can do  outside of loop `red_tables = {'Table 4', 'Table 8'}` and inside of loop:  `col = Fore.RED if k in red_tables else Fore.GREEN`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I'll edit. We don't know exactly what OP wants.

Comment: Since comments are temporary/can be deleted, I prefered adding your suggestion in my answer. Avoids modifying OP data, which is good.

Comment: Thanks guys, Steven's answer fixed everything but thank you all! @Jean init() for some reason "blocked" the rest of the code and solutions worked only when i deleted this, so it seems you were right and it's only required for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so a few things here.. it seems you want to group these tables, you don't provide a good logic for why Table 4 and 8 are red, but those should likely be separate dictionaries.

Then we just define a red and a green print func:

```
def rprint(msg): print (Fore.RED + msg + Fore.RESET)

def gprint(msg): print (Fore.GREEN + msg + Fore.RESET)
```